# unable to install VS code software

Tags: package-management, software-installation, packaging, locate

[E: Unable to locate package vscode.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'vscode.deb'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91EKz.png)

Comment: Yes, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/167115) explains that you need to specify the path to the file when using `apt` or `apt-get` to install a package from a deb file. So assuming the deb file is in your current working directory, instead of `sudo apt install vscode.deb` you would need to use `sudo apt install ./vscode.deb`

Comment: Do you really want to install the package from a `.deb` file you downloaded?  This is a very bad way to install software, especially if you are not very familiar with package management in Ubuntu. If you just need to install this software, look at the answer below to install the snap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install code --classic
```